# Python3.4: printing unpacked variables with / without newline

Tags: python, printing, newline, unpack

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
myStr = "test"

print(myList) # [0, 1, 3]
print(myStr) # test

print(*myList) # 1 2 3
print(*myStr) # t e s t
```

Given that the star (*) operator is supposed to unpack the argument, why aren't the unpacked values printed with newlines between them; i.e. why don't we get:

```
print(*myList)
1
2
3
```

and

```
print(*myStr)
t
e
s
t
```

Comment: Why should `print(*myList)` be different than `print(1,2,3)` where all values are on the same line? What you're looking for is an equivalent for `for c in [1,2,3]: print(c)`.

Answer (score 2):

You unpack the arguments sure, but in order to print on a new line each time you need to give the `print` function the newline separator `\n`, else it just unpacks them all and prints on the same line.

```
print(*myList, sep='\n')
```

**Outputs:**

```
1
2
3
```